# How can I verify the int length of scanner input?

Tags: java, math, input, int, java.util.scanner

I was able to get the program to run and work with error checking to make sure that the user input is in fact an int. The issue I ran into is that I only want it to be a 3-digit int. I'm having trouble getting that into the right place:

```
import java.util.*;

public class listMnemonics

{

   public static void main(String[] args)

   {

   //Defines the "keypad" similar to that of a phone
   char[][] letters = 

   {{'0'},{'1'},{'A','B','C'},{'D','E','F'},{'G','H','I'},{'J','K','L'}, 
   {'M','N','O'},{'P','Q','R','S'},{'T','U','V'},{'W','X','Y','Z'}};

     //Creates the Scanner
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Right here is where I need to implement that and I am running into the issue. I'm sure it's maybe only a line out of place or missing that I need, I just don't know what or where. As it sits, it will constantly ask me to enter a 3-digit number, no matter the length. Error checking for a string entered does currently work:

```
     //Gives instructions to the user to enter 3-digit number
     //Any amount of numbers will work, but instructions help
     //System.out.println("Please enter a 3-digit number: ");

     int j;


     do
     {
     System.out.println("Please enter a 3-digit number: ");

           while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {

     System.out.println("That's not a 3-digit number! Try again!");
     scan.next(); // this is important!
     }

     j = scan.nextInt();

     }



     //while (j <= 0); This works while not checking digit length
     while (j != 3);
     int w = (int) Math.log10(j) +1; //Found this, but not sure if it helps or not

     String n = Integer.toString(w);
```

And here is the rest that get's it to do what I need it to:

```
     //Determines char length based on user input
     char[][] sel = new char[n.length()][];

     for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++)

     {

        //Grabs the characters at their given position
        int digit = Integer.parseInt("" +n.charAt(i));
        sel[i] = letters[digit];

     }

  mnemonics(sel, 0, "");

}

public static void mnemonics(char[][] symbols, int n,  String s) 

{

  if (n == symbols.length)

  {

     System.out.println(s);
     return;

  }

  for (int i = 0; i < symbols[n].length; i ++) 

  {

     mnemonics(symbols, n+1, s + symbols[n][i]);

  }
 }
}
```

Here's the output:

> ----jGRASP exec: java listMnemonics
>    Please enter a 3-digit number:
>    *2345*
>    Please enter a 3-digit number:
>    *12*
>    Please enter a 3-digit number:
>    *123*
>    Please enter a 3-digit number:
>    *motu*
>    That's not a 3-digit number! Try again!

Comment: Is leading zeros a possibility? What's wrong with `nbr > 99 && nbr < 1000`?

Comment: Yes, a leading or ending zero is an acceptable input. If that is the case, where do I put that line? That's my trouble.

Comment: If that is the case, you can't parse it as an `int`. You'll have to read it in as a string and parse it yourself.

Comment: So you're saying instead of: `int j;` I should make it `String j = scan.nextLine();` or something of that nature and then go from there?

Comment: I'm not a java expert by any stretch, most of the time I just get lucky, but that sounds like I may have to change a lot more than expected since after the input I am currently parsing the `int` to a `String` before moving forward. I don't want a `String` to be acceptable input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of MvG and pingul, this is what is currently working the way I was hoping:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class listMnemonics

{

   public static void main(String[] args)

{

   // Defines the "keypad" similar to that of a phone
   char[][] letters = 

   {{'0'},{'1'},{'A','B','C'},{'D','E','F'},{'G','H','I'},{'J','K','L'}, 
   {'M','N','O'},{'P','Q','R','S'},{'T','U','V'},{'W','X','Y','Z'}};

      // Creates the Scanner
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Gives instructions to the user to enter 3-digit number
      // This 'Pattern' also guarantees that only 3 digits works.

      Pattern threeDigitNumber = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{3}");

      int j;

      do

      {

         System.out.println("Please enter a 3-digit phone number: ");

         // If it's not a 3-digit int, try again
         while (!scan.hasNext(threeDigitNumber)) 

            {

            System.out.println("That's not a 3-digit number! Try again!");

            // This is important!
            scan.next(); 

            }

         j = scan.nextInt();

      }

      while (j <= 0);

      String n = Integer.toString(j);


      // Determines char length based on user input
      char[][] sel = new char[n.length()][];

      for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++)

      {

         // Grabs the characters at their given position
         int digit = Integer.parseInt("" +n.charAt(i));
         sel[i] = letters[digit];

      }

   mnemonics(sel, 0, "");

}

// Here is where the magic happens and creates the possible
// letter combinations based on the user input and characters
// selected in previous steps.
public static void mnemonics(char[][] symbols, int n,  String s) 

{

   if (n == symbols.length)

   {

      System.out.println(s);
      return;

   }

   for (int i = 0; i < symbols[n].length; i ++) 

   {

      mnemonics(symbols, n+1, s + symbols[n][i]);

   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Condensed and reformatted your code reads

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int j;
do {
  System.out.println("Please enter a 3-digit number: ");
  while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
     System.out.println("That's not a 3-digit number! Try again!");
     scan.next(); // this is important!
   }
   j = scan.nextInt();
} while (j != 3);
```

Comparing that to [the `Scanner` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) we can see that the `scan.next()` call will read (and discard) the non-int token. Otherwise `j` will be the integer you read. And you continue doing so while the number you read is different from 3. Not the length of the number, but the number itself. So if you want to end the loop, enter `3`. If you want to do so while following the prompt, enter `003`.

If that's not what you want to check, then change the end of loop condition. Or perhaps change the way you test for three-digit numbers, by using regular expressions to match these.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Pattern threeDigitNumber = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d\\d");
int j;
System.out.println("Please enter a 3-digit number: ");
while (!scan.hasNext(threeDigitNumber)) {
  if (scan.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scan.next() + " is not a 3-digit number! Try again!");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Input terminated unepxectedly");
    System.exit(1);
  }
}
j = scan.nextInt();
```

As comments correctly indicate, the pattern `"\\d\\d\\d"` could just as well be written as `"[0-9]{3}"`, or as `"\\d{3}"` or `"[0-9][0-9][0-9]"`. Using `{…}` might be useful in situations where the number of digits is a variable.

The [documentation for `Scanner.hasNext(Pattern)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext(java.util.regex.Pattern)) requires the pattern to match the input. This apparently follows the [`Matcher.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) semantics of matching the whole string against the pattern, as opposed to [`Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) which checks whether the string contains any part matching the pattern. So the input does not have to be enclosed in `^` and `$`, as I assumed at first, and in fact should not be using these unless the pattern is compiled with the [`Pattern.MULTILINE` flag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE).

You may want to call [`Scanner.useDelimiter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.util.regex.Pattern)) to delimit using line breaks only.

```
Scanner.useDelimiter("[\\r\\n]+")
```

Comment: Ahhh, OK. I see what that is doing. When I run the program and enter a 3, it prints `1` as the output. I will remove that. It doesn't seem like it helps.

Comment: @motu: I updated my answer to include a suggestion for how to address your needs.

Comment: Yes, awesome, thank you. I think this is putting me on the right track. The issue I am running into now is that even when I enter a 3-digit number, it doesn't work. It just keeps asking for input.

Comment: [UPDATE] @MvG Using the Pattern class, when I run the program and enter a 3-digit number on the first try, it works. If I run the program and enter a string or any number that is not 3-digits, when I do finally enter 3-digits, it doesn't work.

Comment: [UPDATE] @MvG I got it! I changed your: `Pattern.compile("^\\d\\d\\d$");` to: `Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0,3}");` and that did the trick!

Comment: @motu That will parse a number that has 0-3 digits, if that is what you want you are way better of with just testing `nbr < 1000`.

Comment: @pingul Where would I put that though? Are you saying in place of the `Pattern` solution?

Comment: @motu `do { int nbr = scan.nextInt(); } while (! (nbr < 1000));` And yes, instead of the `Pattern` solution.

Comment: Ok @pingul I'll give that a try. I just need to figure out where to put that. But won't that allow for any number less than 1000? Using that example won't 23 work as well as 623?

Comment: @pingul I see where I messed up. I had to take out the 0 in `{0,3}` to make it `{3}` and now it really is working correctly. Thanks.